# Variable for location of turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a game using turtle in python. I'm trying to code some sort of collision. My original idea is to have a variable be the location of a turtle so, for example, if turtle 1's location/coordinates are equal to that of turtle 2's the game ends. So in layman's terms I want to know if there is a way to turn the location of a turtle into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `pos` method or other methods defined [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#tell-turtle-s-state) to get the location of the turtle.

`pos` returns the position as a `Vec2D` vector. `xcor` and `ycor` return the current x and y coordinates of turtle as `float`.